# Remove extra line in matplotlib sides

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter-canvas

I have a `tabs widget` in `tkinter` form that in one of them `matplotlib` shown plot and histgorams of data:

```
fig = Figure(figsize=(4, 7.75))
self.fig = fig
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=master)
self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='W')
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1)
```

figure has 2 sub-plot using `fig.add_subplot`. This image shown top and bottom of `tab widget` when app is running:

[image]

in around of figure a black line is shown. This line not interested in bottom of tabs (there are 2 lines one for tk tabs and another for figure).

**How can I remove this line or change color of that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
widget.config(highlightcolor="white")
```